# How to cast d-MMM-yyyy into yyyy-mm-dd HH:mm:ss in hive

Tags: apache, hive

I have tried some of the built in functions but I haven't had much luck as they return null. 
Ex: select cast(date_format('1-Nov-2012', 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss') as timestamp) as tstp; returns a null.

Is writing a UDF the only way or am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert the *string* to a *date*, not the other way around.  So, try this:

```
from_unixtime(unix_timestamp('1-Nov-2012' , 'dd-MMM-yyyy'))
```

You can then convert it back to a string, if you really want.

Comment: Thanks Gordon. Ill give this a go!

Comment: It returns a null.

Comment: Try 'MMM' for rmonth